# return child element by name XML

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm a complete beginner at working with XML, so please bear with me...I'm trying to write a simple method to return the first child element by it's specified name.

The method I have is:

```
public Element getChild(Element parent, String childName) {

    NodeList list = parent.getElementsByTagName(*);

    for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        if (list.item(i).getNodeName().equals(childName)) {
            return (Element)list.item(i);
        }
    }
    return null;        
}
```

But, the line `NodeList list = parent.getElementsByTagName(*);` gives me a generic "illegal start of expression" error. Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong? I've been googling for twenty minutes with no luck, which means it's either really obscure or really obvious.

Comment: Note also that `getElementsByTagName` finds all _descendant_ elements that match the test, not just direct children. Your method is called `getChild` but the node it returns might be a child, grandchild, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `*` in quotes: `parent.getElementsByTagName("*")`

Answer (score 0):

```
public Element getChild(Element parent, String childName) {

    NodeList list = parent.getElementsByTagName(childName);
    Node listN=list.item(0);
    NodeList listNC= listN.getChildNodes();
    Element listE=(Element)listNC;
    return listE;        
}
```

It will return only first element with childName in Parent Element. If there is a possibility of more than one occurences, use loop to return list of Elements.